# Cast integer array to void pointer - pthread_create

Tags: c++, type-conversion, void-pointers

for passing arguments, pthread requires void pointer. I want to pass two variables, `int` and `long`. To save myself some trouble, I will pass two `long` instead. So this is what I do:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   /*SOCKET INIT*/
   pthread_t socketTh;
   long data[2] = {ip2l(IP),80};
   pthread_create(&socketTh, 0, &serverConnect, (void*)data);   //ERROR HERE
   while(true) {
       /*event loop*/
   }
   quit_thread(&sockerTh);      //just an EXAMPLE! I don't know how to quit threads, I will google it later
   return 0;
 }
```

#### Error:

> error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(void*)' to 'void* (*)(void*)'

But it seems that this is not the correct way to retype long pointer to void pointer. I wonder not of threads Stackoverflow has suggested me didn't help, as well as any Google search. So maybe, try to explain it really slowly, because I'm beginner and I'm still lost in data types.
Thank you.

**Update:**
I create the `unsigned long*` in main(). This means this variable will last as long as the program itself.

Comment: The casting should work, but note that you are passing a pointer to local data, which will be gone once your function exits. This may not be a problem if you join the thread in that same function.

Comment: The cast is not needed. `data` decays into `unsigned long*`, and that is directly convertible to `void*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message refers to the **third** argument. `pthread_create` wants a pointer to a function that takes a `void*` and returns `void*`. Apparently the function `serverConnect` is a function that takes a `void*` and returns `void`.

Comment: Damnit thatk you. I didn't know that pthread checks for thread function return value. I thought that thread functions can't return anything at all - where would returned data end? If they do, where do I check if thread is over and for its returned value?

Comment: @TomášZato - you should begin by reading the specification for `pthread_create`, easily found through Google.